# Scrolling snackbar issue in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-coordinatorlayout, lazycolumn

I have a Compose view inside a coordinator layout containing an AppBar. inside this compose view there is a lazy column within a scaffold with a snack bar host. I have used rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection to make the connection between the coordinator layout and the lazy layout. the problem is when the lazy column is scrolling if the snackbar is displayed it will also scroll.